# Backend for iOS project

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, client-library

As google app engine infrastructure only supports Java and Python, Am I obliged to write my back-end classes code in one of these languages. If yes, I feel comfortable with Java, so would the workflow be something like this:

```
-Write classes code in Eclipse (Java code).
-Annotate API methods.
-Deploy to Google app engine.
-Generate objective-c client library.
-Connect my app to the cloud end points via the client library.
```

I watched the I/O session about [backend for mobile clients](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4&feature=player_embedded), there was a part on how to generate client library for objective-c, I wonder how they do that.

Am I wrong or missing something?

Comment: If you're not comfortable creating your own back end, you may want to look at [Parse](https://parse.com/)

Comment: The other JVM-hosted languages, along with Google's Go, are also supported on App Engine.

Comment: I would whole-heartedly recommend Parse for this.  There is no need in creating a simplistic backend if one already exists that can be built upon: https://parse.com

Comment: Parse is awesome, but I need to deploy on GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were they talking about the Endpoints feature?

http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/